# How to place the zoomed out div inside the center of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on zoom in and zoom out functionality.

1. The scenario is as follows,  there is a main div and it includes three children *leftside panel*, *rightside panel* and *wrapperdiv*.
2. Both the left and right side panel are collapsible and the *wrapper div* gets adjusted accordingly.
3. The goal is to zoom in and zoom out the content of the *wrapper div*. Lets call it *child div*.
4. The challenge i'm facing right now is that when I *zoom in* the content should stick to the top left corner of the available space of *wrapper div*
5. The second challenge i'm facing is that when i *Zoom out* the child should be centered into the available space of the *wrapper div*.

```js
let zoomArr = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1.5];


var element = document.querySelector('.wireframe');
let value = element.getBoundingClientRect().width / element.offsetWidth;

let indexofArr = zoomArr.indexOf(1);
handleChange = () => {
  let val = document.querySelector('#sel').value;
  val = Number(val)
  console.log('handle change selected value ', val);
  indexofArr = zoomArr.indexOf(val);
  console.log('Handle changes', indexofArr)
  element.style['transform'] = `scale(${val})`
}



document.querySelector('.zoomin').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('value of index zoomin is', indexofArr)
  if (indexofArr < zoomArr.length - 1) {
    indexofArr += 1;
    value = zoomArr[indexofArr];
    document.querySelector('#sel').value = value
    element.style['transform'] = `scale(${value})`
  }
})

document.querySelector('.zoomout').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('value of index  zoom out is', indexofArr)
  if (indexofArr > 0) {
    indexofArr -= 1;
    value = zoomArr[indexofArr];
    document.querySelector('#sel').value = value
    element.style['transform'] = `scale(${value})`
  }
})

document.querySelector('.open-left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-sidepanel')
  leftPanel.classList.toggle('left-toggle')
})


document.querySelector('.open-right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-sidepanel')
  rightPanel.classList.toggle('right-toggle')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

.zoom-header {
  display: flex;
}

.zoomin {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.zoomout {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main-container {
  background: #bdaeae;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-sidepanel {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ecf086;
}

.left-toggle {
  left: -180px;
  position: absolute;
}

.right-toggle {
  right: -180px;
  position: absolute;
}

.right-sidepanel {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #a4f086;
}

.wireframe-container {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ce6edb;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wireframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/b/a/6/190707.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-header">
  <button class="zoomin">zoom in </button>
  <select id="sel" class="select" onchange="handleChange()">
    <option value=0.5>50%</option>
    <option value=0.6>60%</option>
    <option value=0.7>70%</option>
    <option value=0.75>75%</option>
    <option value=0.8>80%</option>
    <option value=0.85>85%</option>
    <option value=0.9>90%</option>
    <option value=1 selected>100%</option>
    <option value=1.2>120%</option>
    <option value=1.5>150%</option>
    <option value=1>reset</option>
  </select>
  <button class="zoomout"> zoom out</button>
  <button class="open-left">Open Left</button>
  <button class="open-right">Open Right</button>
</div>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-sidepanel">
  </div>
  <div class="wireframe-container">
    <div class="wireframe">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-sidepanel">
    asdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is the codepen link to give you an idea what i'm talking about. Thanks in advance.
 https://codepen.io/ghewadesumit/pen/MWwmbbY

Answer (score 0):

You can place "display:flex;" inside the .wireframe-container

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but i'm still struggling to keep it to the top left corner when it is wider than the available space.